# Simplest/most ideal PowerShell function that can accept ALL possible input

Tags: powershell

Is there any simple and short way for a PowerShell function/cmdlet to accept and process all arguments given as piped/positional/undeclared... while still maintaining and accepting any named arguments as well? Essentially, named arguments should be processed separately, and then any and all other arguments should be processed as general input items. Here's a little test suite I wrote for a function that can do this, with the switch argument 'lower' indicating that the result should be in all lowercase:

```
$tests = @(
    @{
        run = { test "a" }
        expected = 'A'
    },

    @{
        run = { test "a" -lower }
        expected = 'a'
    },

    @{
        run = { test "a" "b" }
        expected = 'AB'
    },

    @{
        run = { test "a" "b" "c" }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { test  -lower @("a","b","c") }
        expected = 'abc'
    },

    @{
        run = { test "a" @("b","c") }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { test @("a","b") "c" }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { test "a" @("b") "c" }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { test "a" @("b") @("c") }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },


    @{
        run = { "a" | test }
        expected = 'A'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("a") | test }
        expected = 'A'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("a", "b") | test -lower }
        expected = 'ab'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("a", "b", "c") | test }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { @(@("a", "b", "c")) | test }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("a", @("b", "c")) | test }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { @(@("a", "b"), "c") | test }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("a", @("b"), "c") | test }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("a", @("b"), @("c")) | test }
        expected = 'ABC'
    },


    @{
        run = { "b" | test "a" }
        expected = 'AB'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("b") | test "a" }
        expected = 'AB'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("c", "d") | test @("a", "b") }
        expected = 'ABCD'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("d", "e", "f") | test "a" @("b", "c") }
        expected = 'ABCDEF'
    },

    @{
        run = { "c" | test -lower "a" "b" }
        expected = 'abc'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("e", @("f", "g")) | test @("a", "b") "c" "d" }
        expected = 'ABCDEFG'
    },

    @{
        run = { @(@("e", "f"), "g") | test "a" "b" @("c", "d") }
        expected = 'ABCDEFG'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("d", @("e"), "f") | test @("a", "b") "c" -lower }
        expected = 'abcdef'
    },

    @{
        run = { @("e", @("f"), @("g")) | test "a" @("b", "c") "d" }
        expected = 'ABCDEFG' }
)
```

Running it:

```
$tests | % {
    $actual  =  & $_.run
    if($actual -ne ($_.expected)){ Write-Host "expected: '$($_.expected)', actual: '$actual'" }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected results can be accomplished using this simple function that leverages [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) and [`$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args) automatic variables:

```bash
function test {
    param([switch] $lower)

    $result = -join ($args + $input | Write-Output)
    if ($lower.IsPresent) {
        return $result.ToLower()
    }

    return $result.ToUpper()
}
```